# Как опубликовать картинки в Yii2 при сборке ассетов?

Tags: yii2, изображения

Задача очень простая. У меня есть картинки и иконки всякие. Я держу их в папке с ассетами, допустим, в проекте backend. Хочу, чтоб после запуска этой команды

```
php yii asset console/config/assets/backend.php backend/config/assets.php
```

(которая, я так понимаю, собирает ассеты и доставляет их в публичную папку веб сервера)
мои картинки оказались в публичной папке (то бишь, в web). К сожалению, внятного объяснения в документации, как это сделать, мне обнаружить не удалось. Что то там про публикацию ассетов и ни одного примера с картинками. Был бы очень благодарен за совет, по тому, что именно надо сделать, чтоб картинки загружались в `Web`.

Comment: Ну да, конечно, кто же тут ответит. Кому нафиг нужен этот yii вообще .. эх (